# A program sharing TEXT with its copy (opened twice)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

What i'm trying to do, is a simple program where i have 2 textboxes, and a button.(there is more but no need to say for resolving my problem)
When i write text in the 1st textbox and click the button, it will be written in the 2nd textbox. Everything is ok here.
Now, when i run this program more than once, i want the text to be written in the 2nd textbox of the others programs.
Sorry for the bad explaination i gave you before, hope it's better :)

> OLD DESCRIPTION
>   i'm actually trying to make a program that works pretty much like a
>   messenger (basically 2 textboxes, 1 to send, 1 to view, and a button
>   to send) and i can't figure out how to link the program with itself
>   (copies). 
>  I want it to be able to read the textboxes contained
>   in the other copies and i don't want it to be 1 program with 2 forms,
>   but 1 single form, running severeal times (2 or more) 
>  How can i
>   do that? 
>  /!\ NOTE : It will be on a single computer, just like 2
>   forms!

Comment: Try to spend some more time explaining your problem if you want an answer. "Sharing things" is not suitable here.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. (I'm new here, and every constructive critic is welcome :) )

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are doing this in WinForms and only running one executable.

Sounds like you you want to create a single instance of a class that is shared between several forms. It should raise an event when the values change. After you create each instance of your form you pass in the class. In the form you would declare it `With Events`. When one form updates the class it would raise an event notifying the other forms to refresh themselves.

If you are familiar with WPF and MVVM this sort of design would be a little cleaner, but that takes some time to get up to speed on.

This design would not be appropriate if you want to run seperate applications and communicate between them.

Comment: The OP said explicitly: *i don't want it to be 1 program with 2 forms, but 1 single form, running severeal times*

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some kind of [*IPC*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), respectively *remoting*.

You could use:

- [anonymous pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx)
- [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx#Y0)
- [UDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx)
- [TCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)
- [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (would be overkill IMHO)
- [windows messaging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17606/NET-Interprocess-Communication) (would be the easiest way)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the network, as i said it'll be one application, launched 2 times or more, on a single computer.
I just want to take the text like from one form to another, but it's 2 programs! thx anyway

Comment: @Nan0_Zor It does not matter if you want to communicate over a network or just locally (except for anonymous pipes, which only work locally). All methods I mentioned are working fine when just used locally.

Comment: I already understood your old description. The running processes have to communicate with each other in some way, and I listed five different ways to do this.