# Communication between exe?

Tags: c#, vb.net, tcp, named-pipes

I have several users on a single Windows Server 2012 (they are using Remote Desktop).

I have two (vb.net) programs, that need to communicate with eachothers - that is ... each user have two applications that need to communicate.

What is the easies (and most realiable) approach to have two apps communicate while several instances is running on the same box (on instance per RDS user)?

Thanks!

Comment: which one is easiest as per you?

Comment: what have your tried?

Comment: What are your requirements? Performance? Comparability (could the two programs be of different version)? Asynchronous or synchronous? Can you just start the other we exe in process? Can more than one user be logged on to each server?

Comment: possible duplicate: [A program sharing TEXT with its copy (opened twice)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049865/a-program-sharing-text-with-its-copy-opened-twice)

Comment: I mentioned a few possibilities [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13051449/142637), also have a look at this article: [.NET Interprocess Communication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17606/NET-Interprocess-Communication) for an interessting approach.

Comment: Most important is, that it works everytime. Yes several users are logged on the same box at the same time. Yes programs can be of different versions.

Comment: One idea I had was to use FileSystemWatcher and create a file with the info - but I dunno if that's a good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're a lot of options:

- Message queue (for, example, [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx)).
- [ASP.NET WebAPI self-host](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api)
- [WCF self-host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx).
- ...

Maybe, in your case, I would go for the use of message queues. And, since MSMQ comes with Windows (in order to install it, go to Add/remove Windows features in Control Panel) and .NET Framework has support for it out-of-the-box, it could be a good choice.

### Side-note

*When I mention WCF/WebAPI self-host, I mean that each process can have a very tiny REST or SOAP (or whatever) API that may allow that any of the whole processes may act as clients and/or servers. It's a good way of having interprocess messaging*

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. Since MSMQ only have 1 queue on a TS/RDS server, all users on the same server will have to process messages eventhough they are not meant for them - and that will cause an unnessacary overload - right?

Comment: WebApi self-host sound VERY interesting, but that will require a sepearate program to run.

Comment: @MojoDK No, you don't need a separate program. Its *self-host*. Read it "as is". You can "embed" a WebAPI in your current EXE.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1) Use the SendMessage api - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

2) Run a client-server http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12318/Building-Client-Server-applications-with-VB-NET-fo

3) Use UDP broadcasting http://www.solidautomation.com/bryon/Using_UDP_and_Winsock_in_Visual_Basic_6.htm

Comment: SendMessage - won't that cuase a problem, when there's like 10-15 versions of the same program running on the same box (one per user)?

Comment: Maybe - I think you can broadcast messages to all listening applications

Answer (score 1):

Available options ***inter process communication*** would be: 
[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) 
[Remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/process_communication.aspx/process_communication.aspx) 
[ASP.Net WebSevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) 
[WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011.aspx)
[Socket programing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301275/Chatting-using-CSocket)

[Interprocess Communications on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be resource